# How do I find my Raspberry Pi on a big LAN?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, wpa2-eap

I'm a college kid on a WPA2 Enterprise with a Raspberry Pi on ethernet. How do I find this device on the network?

I could try running

```
arp -a
```

logging results to a file, connecting my Pi, and then diffing by rerunning

```
arp -a
```

but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

- If you know its dns name you can simply ping it.
- You could use [arping](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/arping.8.html) to ping its MAC
- You could configure it to send you an email with its IP once the connection is established...

Answer (score 1):

ARP is a [Layer 2 protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer), so if the device is on a different subnet you won't be able to find it by MAC address.

Your 2 best options are:

1. Record it's IP before you deploy it, `ip a`
2. Setup a listener on another computer and configure a reverse shell on the pi to call that computer once it's network stack is established.  At least one of these methods should suite you, [Reverse Shell Cheat Sheet](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/shells/reverse-shell-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways, but if you can search from the same subnet, I would use a zeroconf/Bonjour lookup.

[This page](http://elinux.org/RPi_Advanced_Setup) has a ton of setup information.  Search on the page for "avahi" for more detailed instructions.  But the basics are to install the avahi daemon and start it running, then connect from an OS that understands Bonjour or Zeroconf names.  Ubuntu should be okay out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a completely fresh installation u can try

```
nmap -A 192.168.1.*
```

then look for an open ssh on port 22, else u may have to start a long service detection scan on all 65k ports using the following:

```
nmap -p- -sV 192.168.1.*
```

Since its common practice to move ssh/vnc and other services on other ports uve got a good chance finding your own machine again this way.

Of course this is impractical if the RasPi is using DHCP, so i would hurry and follow bowlofred´s advice or look into other solutions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if network admins would like that...

Comment: If you looking for only port 22, then you should tell nmap that with `-p 22`. Will be much faster without probing all the ports you don't care about.